# SyntaxError: Missing semicolon when trying to export Mongo Atlas collection to local machine

Tags: database, mongodb, command-line, mongodb-atlas

I am having a problem exporting a collection from Mongo Atlas to my local machine. I have tried several different formats including this one, which I found in the official Atlas documentation on importing and exporting data.

First I log into my Atlas like so:

`mongosh "mongodb+srv://cluster0.oyvrw.mongodb.net/dbname" --username uname`

Then I try the command from the official docs:

`mongoexport --uri mongodb+srv://uname:password@cluster0.oyvrw.mongodb.net/dbname --collection colname --type json --out cats.json`

I have looked around at other similar questions and tried everything I can find online without success. One suggestion was not to run the command from the mongo shell but from the regular command line, but this does not work either.

It seems like it should be easier to get a collection out of Atlas to JSON. Any help or suggestions are much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: `mongoexport` is not a  mongo shell command, it is a binary included in the database-tools package.

Comment: @Joe thanks for the response. As I mentioned, I did see that it wasn't supposed to be run in the mongo shell, but the command didn't work in the system shell either. But I looked more into it and noticed `mongo-database-tools` must now be installed separately. The docs missed that little detail. I've got it working now so will post it as an answer to help others avoid the pain.

Answer (score 6):

For anyone facing this error, the  `mongoexport` command does not work with `mongosh`. It must be run with the system shell.

However, `mongoexport` is part of `mongo-database-tools`, which as of MongoDB 4.4, is released separately. As a result, running `mongoexport` in the system shell will throw a `command not found` if the installed version of MongoDB is 4.4 or greater.

To solve this you can install the database tools using homebrew:

`brew install mongodb/brew/mongodb-database-tools`

Of course, make sure you have homebrew already installed. If not a quick Google will help.

Then following command should work to perform an export:

`mongoexport --uri mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>@cluster0.oyvrw.mongodb.net/<dbName> --collection <collectionName> --type json --out /Users/macuser/desktop/exportBU.json`

Hope that helps anyone having similar problems getting data in/out of MongoDB.

Comment: you can also get an msi for windows on their download page https://www.mongodb.com/try/download/database-tools?tck=docs_databasetools